# Vmware vCloud director browse button do not work

Tags: firefox, vmware

I am using vmware director and i want to upload an iso image but the browse button do not work as you would expect it to.

i took this screenshot

[image]

I have masked the company details for privacy reasons.I am using firefox and my java plugin for firefox is fine.I know this since i can see the media upload dialog as shown in the image.What could be wrong with the upload button?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this kb article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2069664) will help. It worked for me in IE with what *appears* to be the same version of Windows. The fix should apply to Firefox as well, as it involves java settings that apply to the "Mozilla Family".

Essentially you'll be whitelisting your vCloud instance; the article has more detailed steps.